# How to add one value from two values to parameter key in swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, button

My AddEventViewController contains Two Buttons 1) PublishEvent 2)DraftEvent

here if i click publisheventBtn then event should display in publish segment.. if i click DraftBtn then event should go to draft segment

**for that i have JSON parameter like below:** here how to change `status` key value according to buttonclick means if i click PublishEvent then i have to give `status = "Publish"` and if i click draftButn then `status = "Draft"`

```
let parameter = ["status":"Draft", "eventName": eventNameField.text, "eventMessage": msgTextfild.text, "eventDate": Fromdate, "eventTime": fromTime, "eventEndDate": Todate, "eventEndTime": toTime, "isAllDayEvent":"false", "isEventRepeatable":"false"] as [String : Any]
```

remaining code:

```
func AddEvent(){

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
        if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
            do {
                let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String :AnyObject]
               let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventsViewController") as! EventsViewController
                viewController.eventType = "Published"
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                }
            }
            catch  {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        else {
            self.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter vaild details")
        }
    }
})
dataTask.resume()
}


@IBAction func publishNewEvent(_ sender: Any) {

    addNewEvents()
}
@IBAction func draftEvent(_ sender: Any) {

addNewEvents()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURL` in Swift. And a JSON dictionary value is never `AnyObject`, it's `Any`. And `.allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a collection type. And name functions always with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: @vadian, thank you.. i will keep these words in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator `?` to assign value to a `status` variable and assign it the proper value according to the conditions.

```
let status = didClickDraftButton ? "Draft" : "Publish"
let parameter = ["status": status, ...]
```

Set the value of `didClickDraftButton` accordingly. Here's an example:

```
var didClickDraftButton = true // default value or could use optional if you want

@IBAction func publishNewEvent(_ sender: Any) {
    didClickDraftButton = false
    addNewEvents()
}
@IBAction func draftEvent(_ sender: Any) {
    didClickDraftButton = true
    addNewEvents()
}
```

Comment: here what is `didClickDraftButton `

Comment: `didClickDraftButton` is a `Bool`. Set `true` when you click the draft button and `false` otherwise.

Comment: can u show how to add one value from two values to status without using `didClickDraftButton `

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Besides, What is the reason for not using `didClickDraftButton` property?

Comment: that is for `EventsViewController ` here i need to pass either Draft or Published right? then only JSON api works na `eventType`

Comment: i mean without any butn i need to pass any one value to variable `eventType `

Comment: I'm not sure how you're planning to pass data without a trigger(Button). Why don't you ask this on another post with all the relevant details and post the link in the comments so that I could take a look :)